# How do I make a button reusable?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am relatively new to the world of programming.  I have a sturdy knowledge of HTML and CSS, and recently picked up JavaScript.  I am working on a series of text generators as a school project; my goal is to be able to, on the website, click a button and have the computer spit out random text each time you click the button.  However, while I have a good grasp on HTML and JavaScript, my knowledge on how to combine the two to give a webpage functionality is virtually nonexistent.

I created a "Shakespearean Insult Generator" using JavaScript, which is functional, and I figured out how to add a button to a page so that when you click the button, it prints a randomly generated insult to the page:

```
<script>
var adjective1 = ["artless", "bawdy", "beslubbering"...
var adjective2 = ["base-court", "bat-fowling", "beef-witted"...
var noun = ["apple-john", "baggage", "barnacle"...

var insult = "Thou art a " + adjective1[Math.floor(Math.random() * 60)] + ", " + adjective2[Math.floor(Math.random() * 60)] + ", " + noun[Math.floor(Math.random() * 60)] + "!";

var genInsult = function() {
x=document.getElementById("replace");  
x.innerHTML=insult;    
};
</script>

<p id= "replace">Your insult will appear here!</p>
<button type="button" onclick="genInsult()">Generate Insult</button>
```

However, once you press the button once, you cannot press it again to generate another insult unless you refresh the page.

So my question is: how can I make this button reusable by using JavaScript?

I've tried searching for an answer to my question, but the problem is that I'm so new to JavaScript that I often have trouble understanding other people's questions and the answers to them.  Also, a lot of responses reference jQuery, a language I do not know. If anyone has a solution within the realm of JavaScript, I would be extremely grateful!

I might not know a heck of a lot now, but I am very eager to learn!

Comment: Side note, you can replace the 60 with adjective1.length

Comment: YES... just fixed that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move this:

```
var insult = "Thou art a " + adjective1[Math.floor(Math.random() * 60)] + ", " + adjective2[Math.floor(Math.random() * 60)] + ", " + noun[Math.floor(Math.random() * 60)] + "!";
```

within your `genInsult()` function and you should be good. Right now it's outside so it will only generate once.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been stated, your main issue is just that the creation of the insult is outside of your function, so it is only created once, rather than each time the function is called. I really enjoy re-factoring code, I wanted to offer you this: [(click here for live demo)](http://jsbin.com/ObOyIta/1/edit)

I have written your app using an object oriented pattern and cleaning up a lot of mess and inefficiency. I think it will do you a lot of good to study this and learn all you can!! By the way, don't ever use inline javascript (the click function in your html) unless you're using a framework that makes sense of it (like AngularJS).

```
<p id="insult">Your insult will appear here!</p>
<button type="button" id="generate">Generate Insult</button>
```

and the js:

```
var generator = { //only one global variable!!
  init: function() { //this sets up your app for use
    var elem = document.getElementById('insult');

    var obj = this; //cache reference to the generator object (the "this" pointer will be changed within the click function
    var button = document.getElementById('generate');
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      elem.innerText = obj.generateInsult();
    });
  },
  generateInsult: (function() { //use an IIFE to give a nice closure to these variables
    var generateInsult = function() {
      return "Thou art a "+adjs1[r(adjs1)]+", "+adjs2[r(adjs2)]+", "+nouns[r(nouns)]+"!";
    };
    function r(arr) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length); 
    }
    var adjs1 = ["artless", "bawdy", "beslubbering"];
    var adjs2 = ["base-court", "bat-fowling", "beef-witted"];
    var nouns = ["apple-john", "baggage", "barnacle"];
    return generateInsult;
  }())
};

generator.init(); //I suggest running this on document ready to be sure the elements are loaded. If not, this will not work. Keep that in mind!
```

Comment: Nice job! My only nitpick: I know part of the idea of that closure is to prevent those arrays from being initialized more than once, but isn't that a bit overkill for a beginner? It also means the vertical line order doesn't quite match the actual order it executes, so even amature coders might get a bit confused reading that. If you feel like changing it, I might also consider giving `r()` a more descriptive name - though I admit that makes the generate function wordier.

Comment: Small matter first: the reason behind the name `r()` is just as you said - to keep the return statement understandable. I figured it stood for random and makes enough sense. It's also pretty clear what it does just looking at it. You may have missed my point with the closure. Nothing else needs to know about the arrays or the random function, so they are private to `generateInsult()`. It does a good job of showing the code's intent. There really is no run order here, but even if there were my pattern summarizes things and then expands on them. That helps readability.

Comment: It's like saying - what is my code going to do? Add a click function to a button that generate's an insult. That is the first thing you see in my code. It's quite intuitive that way. Then you can investigate the `generateInsult()` function and see a summary of what it does...then investigate those things further. I write flow first and details last.

Comment: Yeah, everything around init: {} seems fine. My point was just that you could write "generateInsult: function() { var adjs = ... }", include those variables inline, no need to return a seperate function. You will have a negligibly small performance hit by initializing them on each click, but...premature optimization, much? It depends on whether your focus is readability and simplicity, or on perfection execution-wise. As with all functions, you can determine r()'s meaning by finding the function, but for slow readers that could mean eyes travelling forward, down, up, forward...

Comment: Well, to each his own :) There are plenty of patterns and styles that are good. The important thing is that they at least attempt to be perfectly dry, readable, encapsulated, efficient, etc, though there are always trade-offs.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm definitely going to review your edits so I can streamline my app... :)