# Several questions about coding javascript OOP style

Tags: javascript

I am learning to code Javascript OOP style and I have a few questions, mostly about declaring variables and not using global ones.

**Question 1** - am I doing the following coding correctly?

Here i declare the **"Fields"** class:

```
/**
 * Display Fields
 */
var Fields = function(){

    this.display = function(fields){

        var test = '1st method of declaring test';
        this.test = '2nd method of declaring test';

        for (var i = 0, len = fields.length; i < len; i++) {

            jQuery('[name=' + fields[i] + ']').closest('.row').css('display', 'block');

        }
    };
}
```

Now I instantiate the class **Fields**, creating the object **fields**

```
// Fields Object
var fields = new Fields();

fields.display(requiredFields.concat(normalFields));
```

**Question 2** - Which is the correct way of declaring class variables - in this case: **"test"**:

```
this.test = 'value'
```

or just:

```
var test = 'value'
```

Can you explain why 1 method is preferred over the other?

**Question 3** - is the **"i"** inside the for loop declared correctly? Is this the correct way of doing it?  Or I need to be using something like:

**this.i = 0**

**Any advice on good practices is strongly appreciated.**

*I read allot on the net but I am new to OOP altogether and I want to make sure I am on a correct path.*

Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is OK.
2. If you use `this.test = 'value'` and `var test2 = 'value'`, then you can do `fields.test`, but cannot do `fields.test2`.
3. It is correct. Your i should be local variable in this context.

Comment: --- this.test --- is very interesting, it's like declaring private variables - I did this coding oop in php

Comment: No, it is like declaring a public variable.

Answer (score 1):

[This would be worth a read. It's all about Javascript scope.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/)

[this (pun intended) is also worth a read. It's about 'this' in Javascript.](http://www.impressivewebs.com/javascript-this-different-contexts/)

[A quick read on OOP in Javascript.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-basics-of-object-oriented-javascript/)

After reading through all those and understanding, you may want to look into Javascript design patterns.

Answer (score 1):

`var` should only be used if you want to create a variable in the scope of the class, and as far as I know, variables in that scope cannot be read externally, unless they are read from a function inside the same class constructor. This can also be used to create private variables.

`this` refers to the object that will be created when you use `new Classname()`, and you can add properties to it that will be available for use. You are doing this correctly. You can also use the bracket notation, like this: `this['i have spaces'] = 'Me too!'`, which can also be read out later, using `class['i have spaces']`, this allows for adding properties that have operators or other JS syntax characters inside.

To answer you second question, you need to decide wether or not you want the user to access this variable. If you want them to have access, then use `this.test`, otherwise `var test`.

And as for the third, yes.

Comment: Ty DJDavid - so basically what you are saying is that declaring: this.test is like declaring a public property --- while declaring var test is like declaring a private one

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have "classes". Javascript uses prototypical inheritance based on objects. There are a lot of OOP patterns that are good. If I were you, since the idea is "Object Oriented" I would start with an object, whereas you have a function (which is technically an object itself, but bear with me). Check this out:

```
  var fields = { //this can be the only global variable we ever use.
    options: {
      //default properties object.
    },
    init: function() {
      //do some things that need setup
      this.$elem = $('.myElem'); //for example
    },
    run: function(options) { //describe a general flow here, then write the functions to execute that, again, this is just an example of what might make sense. There are many approaches.
      this.init(); //maybe this is all you need to kick off your app and you could call it at document.ready. Don't let me example make you think too strictly. These are just ideas.
      var data = this.getData();
      this.useData(data);
    }
    getData: function() {
       var data;
       var example = 'blah'; //no need for everything to be a property of the object (this)
       //whatever here, probaby async request, so use promises
       return data;
    }
    //etc
  }

fields.run(); //you could pass some options, by the way. Whatever you do here, it should kick off the app and make everything do what it does. Calling this `init()` often makes more sense, btw.
```

Your question isn't particularly about inheritance, [but here is a nice read on that.](http://blog.javascriptroom.com/2013/01/21/the-initializer-pattern/)
`Object.create(myObj)` is nice :)

[Here is a recent answer of mine (click)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626794/how-do-i-make-a-button-reusable/18627044#18627044) that shows a real (and simple) app written OOP style, with [a live demo (click)](http://jsbin.com/ObOyIta/1/edit) you can mess around with.

If you have any specific questions about this, follow up with a comment and I'll be glad help! It is good of you to want to follow better practices!

Comment: Ty very much m59 - every answer is worth reading - I just got great resources from you and the guys. The thing is, I want to code javascript very close to the php oop coding style since I am planning to move to php development in the future - and this will be a solid helping stone.

Comment: That is simply not feasible. Javascript doesn't have classes and attempting to recreate is only going to cause difficulty. I believe that's called "pseudo-classical" and I have only heard it considered a bad idea in javascript. I write OOP in both javascript and php and can assure it would be better to not relate the two.

Comment: It's not necessarily a bad idea. Since it's *close* to classical OO, it can be a lot more comfortable for people who don't know prototypical OO. Using functions as constructors is a legitimate technique, and can be used effectively. The author of the linked article just believes it to be inferior, partially because of legitimate, logical reasons, and partially due to personal preference. Check out [The Illusion of Class](http://blog.javascriptroom.com/2013/01/29/the-illusion-of-class/) (by the same author (me)) for more information.

Comment: Heheh, from what source do you suppose I came to my current conclusions :) You might recall that I was once attempting to write pseudo-classical. I learned js and php OOP within the same general time period. Both are fairly simple to me now, but I am continually disappointed with php's lack of flexibility as compared to js. The principles are the same, but I can't help but recommend using a js pattern that maximizes the flexibility (gives you more options) rather than one that simulates php's restrictiveness. Anyway, as I have had to say often lately, to each his own.